# Linking to Javascript-Sourced Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The New York State Legislature provides an online version of the Laws of New York (criminal, civil, vehicle and traffic, etc.) at http://public.leginfo.state.ny.us/navigate.cgi.  From that starting page, to view a particular statute the user has to click on Laws (menu bar option) > Laws of New York > [Chapter acronym, e.g. "PEN"] and then drill down through Titles and Articles to the statute itself.

Each html link in that process takes the format of a link to javascript code; for example:

```
<a href=javascript:getlaw("LAWS","$$PEN155.25$$@TXPEN0155.25","LAW")> 155.25</a> - Petit larceny.
```

It seems to me that the statutory text for the offense of Penal Law section 155.25 (Petit Larceny) is held in a database that is accessed by javascript for display on screen.

My question is, is it possible for me to write HTML or javascript that links from my webpage directly to that statutory text so that the user doesn't have to navigate through the Legislature's menu system?

Comment: nope. not unless said site supports deep linking to said text.

Comment: I would contact them and ask if they have a public API you can connect with. They are using a JS method for loading so they seem to not want the info easily directly linked to.

Comment: Looking through the AJAX for `getlaw` made me cringe. Unless you write a crawler to gather all the contents for each subdirectory through chained POST requests and store them on your own database, it looks like you'll have to subject your user to navigating the site directly.

Comment: Maybe. It looks like it is just a simple form post that's happening. I can't get all the values quite right but here's a sample form that gets you close: http://jsfiddle.net/o2psv0yn/. I don't have enough time right now to dig into it deeper but you might be able to submit all the correct values to post directly to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto the following solution, which doesn't use JavaScript:

```
<a href="http://public.leginfo.state.ny.us/lawssrch.cgi?NVLWO:+&HWEBPAGE=LAWS+&QLAWDATA=$$PEN155.25$$@TXPEN0155.25"> 155.25</a> - Petit larceny.
```

[155.25](http://public.leginfo.state.ny.us/lawssrch.cgi?NVLWO:+&HWEBPAGE=LAWS+&QLAWDATA=$$PEN155.25$$@TXPEN0155.25) - Petit larceny.

To construct a link, you need the QLAWDATA string for the desired law section (in the above example, "$$PEN155.25$$@TXPEN0155.25").  As indicated in the original question, you can get it from the "href=javascript:getlaw(...)" string.

I've tried it out on several different NY Law sections, and it appears to work consistently.  Some sample QLAWDATA strings from Chapter ISC (Insurance):
"$$ISC4222$$@TXISC04222", "@LLISC", "@SLISC0A91", "@SLISC0A49T2"